# Response authorization with Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey 2 application containing resources that consume and produce json. My requirement is to add a signature to an Authorization response header generated from a combination of various piece of response data (similar to the Amazon Webservices request signature). One of these pieces of data is the response body but I cant see that there are any filter or interception points that will allow me access to the json content. I imagine this is mainly because the response outputstream is for writing not reading.

Any ideas as to how I can read the response body - or alternative approaches ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that when your application is responding to a request, you want to modify the `Authorization` header by adding a signature to it's value.

If that's the case, you want to implement a `ContainerResponseFilter`:

```
public class MyContainerResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        // You can get the body of the response from the ContainerResponseContext
        Object entity = containerResponseContext.getEntity();
        // You'll need to know what kind of Object the entity is in order to do something useful though
        // You can get some data using these functions
        Class<?> entityClass = containerResponseContext.getEntityClass();
        Type entityType = containerResponseContext.getEntityType();

        // And/or by looking at the ContainerRequestContext and knowing what the response entity will be
        String method = containerRequestContext.getMethod();
        UriInfo uriInfo = containerRequestContext.getUriInfo();

        // Then you can modify your Authorization header in some way
        String authorizationHeaderValue = containerResponseContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        authorizationHeaderValue = authorizationHeaderValue + " a signature you calculated";
        containerResponseContext.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorizationHeaderValue);
    }
}
```

Be warned that the `filter` function will be called for all requests to your application, even when Jersey couldn't find a matching resource for the request path, so you may have to do some extra checking.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @oggmonster - I had encountered the ContainerResponseFilter but it looked to me like it only gave me the entity object before it had been transformed into json. I kind of wanted to use the json version of the response body in the signature as that would be what the client had available to it to generate a signature for comparison. All the interception points seemed to be before the entity had been rendered as json.

Comment: Why does it need to be JSON? If you have an object which Jackson is marshalling, but it hasn't been marshalled, just cast it to your object and get what you need from there. If that's really not an option, then explicitly serialize your object to JSON when creating your response, then read the entity as a string in the `ContainerResponseFilter`

Comment: Thanks. I have gone with creating the json in the resource and generating the signature there.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.11/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) in order to access the content, and once you are finished with your interception logic, forward it to the request. E.g.

```
import java.io.*;

import com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;


public class ExampleFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest req) {

        try(InputStream in = req.getEntityInputStream(); ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
            if (in.available() > 0) {
                StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
                ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

                byte[] entity = out.toByteArray();            
                if (entity.length > 0) {
                    content.append(new String(entity)).append("\n");
                    System.out.println(content);
                }

                req.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(entity));
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //handle exception
        }

        return req;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I was trying to add an Authorization header to the response so the client could trust it came from a valid server.